# Integrating TypeScript with build tools

Tags: typescript

I just joined a new team working on ASP.Net MVC project using TypeScript (2.0) and Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) as IDE. I have a requirement to update TypeScript version to 2.7.

I started looking at the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html), and I can see that we are using [MSBuild](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#msbuild) option since We have the same settings under `csproj` file. 
To change TypeScript version, I have to install TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2015 and put the right version in `csproj` file.

I don't like this approach because I have to install TypeScript SDK manually in each machine that will build the project. So I was thinking about using [Gulp](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#gulp). But I'm having some concerns here.

If I use `Gulp` instead of `MSBuild`:

1. Will Visual Studio work properly with TypeScript (compilation errors and debugging)?
2. Where can I setup TypeScript compiler version for [`Gulp` task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript)?

Answer (score 0):

> I started looking at the documentation, and I can see that we are using MSBuild option since We have the same settings under csproj file. To change TypeScript version, I have to install TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2015 and put the right version in csproj file.

The install of the SDK isn't mandatory, you could use [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/).

For auto-completion in VS, you need the SDK, but maybe is a bit different version not a problem.

Also note that you could easily install multiple TypeScript SDKs side-by-side

Comment: Can I only use TypeScript SDK locally in dev machine and rely on Gulp task on CI machine?

Comment: I pretty sure you can. We use the MSbuild package on the CI, and locally the SDK. If it won't work out-of-the-box, it definitely works by setting (conditional) `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` , See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html